# No Response message from any snmpget or snmpwalk

Tags: configuration, snmp, service

I have installed `net-snmp` on my Windows XP and I have configured the SNMP service on my router and my machine, but when I try to make an `snmpwalk` or an `snmpget`, I receive always a message `No response` or `time-out`:

```
>snmpwalk -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1
Timeout: No Response from 127.0.0.1
```

Why is this happening? Is it the problem with my router? (TG585v7)? Or am I using the command incorrectly?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. From what I can gather you have installed `net-snmp` under Windows XP and you are attempting to do an `snmpwalk` to your router? It looks as if you are trying to do an `snmpwalk` on you loopback device, though I am not sure why? Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute the following command:

`snmpwalk -v 1 -c public [IP Address of your router]`

You are trying to do an SNMP walk of your local computer. Which is totally possible, but even when you install the SNMP role on Windows you need to then configure it (by default it comes locked down).

To configure SNMP on Windows, go to the Services control panel, find the SNMP service, go to Properties, and then have a look through the SNMP-specific tabs.

Comment: +1 also make sure that you configure `SNMP` on the router itself if you are attempting to do an `snmpwalk` of the router. Most routers come with `public` as the default community but this is not always the case.